# Exception has been throw: rowIndex > available rows: 2 > 1

Tags: android, realm

I'm actually doing an application using Realm and I'm having some troubles.

I'm loading a list in my activity with some information stored in my Realm DB, it works pretty fine with 2 elements in the list but when I add the third and try to load the activity, this exception is throw

11-07 16

```
:54:28.829 11829-11829/com.list.buffet.alvaro.buffetlist E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.list.buffet.alvaro.buffetlist/com.list.buffet.alvaro.buffetlist.SavedListActivity}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: rowIndex > available rows: 2 > 1
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2351)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLauchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:165)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1373)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5391)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: rowIndex > available rows: 2 > 1
    at io.realm.internal.TableView.nativeGetSourceRowIndex(Native Method)
    at io.realm.internal.TableView.getSourceRowIndex(TableView.java:111)
    at io.realm.RealmResults.get(RealmResults.java:215)
    at com.list.buffet.alvaro.buffetlist.SavedListActivity.saveListInMap(SavedListActivity.java:166)
    at com.list.buffet.alvaro.buffetlist.SavedListActivity.addElementsToList(SavedListActivity.java:156)
    at com.list.buffet.alvaro.buffetlist.SavedListActivity.onCreate(SavedListActivity.java:43)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1150)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2315)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:165) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1373) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5391) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600) 
    at dalvik.sys
```

The method throwing this exception is:

```
private void saveListInMap() {
    for (int i = 0; i < listItems.size(); i++) {
        SavedList savedList = new SavedList();
        RealmResults<FoodList> queryListName = realm.where(FoodList.class)
                .equalTo("listName", listItems.get(i))
                .findAll();
        savedList.setListName(queryListName.get(i).getListName());
        savedList.setRestaurantName(queryListName.get(i).getRestaurantName());
        addElementsToList(savedList, queryListName);
        plateMap.put(i,savedList);
    }
}

private void addElementsToList(SavedList savedList, RealmResults<FoodList> queryListName) {
    for (int j = 0; j < queryListName.size(); j++) {
        savedList.addToList(queryListName.get(j).getFoodPlate());
    }
}
```

My realm object:

```
public class FoodList extends RealmObject {
    private int id;
    private String foodPlate;
    private String listName;
    private String restaurantName;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFoodPlate() {
        return foodPlate;
    }

    public void setFoodPlate(String foodPlate) {
        this.foodPlate = foodPlate;
    }

    public String getListName() {
        return listName;
    }

    public void setListName(String listName) {
        this.listName = listName;
    }

    public String getRestaurantName() {
        return restaurantName;
    }

    public void setRestaurantName(String restaurantName) {
        this.restaurantName = restaurantName;
    }
}
```

I don't know what could be, im a bit frustrated.

Comment: What version of Realm are you using?

Comment: Btw it's because you have 2 items in `listItems`, and you have 1 item in your RealmResults - but if you used RealmResults directly then this stuff doesn't happen as long as you register a RealmChangeListener to handle changes

Comment: Still don't know how to fix it, could you explain it to me please.

Comment: Nvm fixed it, thanks, you were damn right! ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I finally got my solution, it was very simple:

```
private void saveListInMap() {
    for (int i = 0; i < listItems.size(); i++) {
        SavedList savedList = new SavedList();
        RealmResults<FoodList> queryListName = realm.where(FoodList.class)
                .equalTo("listName", listItems.get(i))
                .findAll();

        addElementsToList(savedList, queryListName);
        plateMap.put(i,savedList);
    }
}

private void addElementsToList(SavedList savedList, RealmResults<FoodList> queryListName) {
    for (int j = 0; j < queryListName.size(); j++) {
        savedList.setListName(queryListName.get(i).getListName());
        savedList.setRestaurantName(queryListName.get(i).getRestaurantName());
        savedList.addToList(queryListName.get(j).getFoodPlate());
    }
}
```

Just had to add the setters into the loop... Otherwise I would be trying to access a position that doesn't exist in the array.

Hope I could help someone with this trouble.